# Selenium/Python: How do I move to a new window with no window name given?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I need to switch to a new window that opens after clicking a link. I don't have a window name nor a target from the link, so move_to.window() is throwing an exception. How can I switch to the new window?

Edit: I am using driver.switch_to.window() to grab the last index of the window handle list. Selenium seems to be grabbing the other window and performing the first action following, which is selecting an option from a drop down. However immediately after selecting the item, a NoSuchElementException is thrown stating that the element that I JUST performed an action on was not able to be located. Here is my Python code:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href=\"link_that_opens_other_window\"]").click()

    Select(driver.find_element_by_id("programID")).select_by_value("621")

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., \"New Schedule Wizard\")]").click()

    config.long_rest() # short_rest() and long_rest() are custom functions I defined to wait for pages to load

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    config.short_rest()

    # In newly opened window, import old rotations
    Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name = \"rotationsetID\"]")).select_by_value("16")
    Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name = \"scheduleID\"]")).select_by_index(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=\"Next Step >\"]").click()
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name = "rotationsetID"]"}
(Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

I have also tried treating the new window as a frame but that has not worked either.

Edit: The most recent code I have tried:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href=\"link_that_opens_other_window\"]").click()

    Select(driver.find_element_by_id("programID")).select_by_value("621")

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., \"New Schedule Wizard\")]").click()

    config.long_rest() # short_rest() and long_rest() are just custom functions I defined to wait for pages to load

    old_window = driver.window_handles[0]
    new_window = driver.window_handles[-1]

    print "Old: ", type(old_window), old_window
    print "New: ", type(new_window), new_window

    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)

    print "Current window: ", driver.current_window_handle # this line prints out the same value as new_window

    config.short_rest()

    # In newly opened window, import old rotations
    Select(driver.find_element_by_name("rotationsetID")).select_by_value("16")
    Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name = \"scheduleID\"]")).select_by_index(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value=\"Next Step >\"]").click()
```

Edit: Here is the HTML code with the element I am trying to grab:

```
<table cellspacing="8" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Academic Year:  </td>
      <td>
        <select name="rotationsetID" onchange="selectAcYearSchedule(this);">
          <option value="0">(select academic year)</option>
          <option value="13">July 1, 2013 - June 30, 2014</option>
          <option value="14">July 1, 2014 - June 30, 2015</option>
          <option value="15">July 1, 2015 - June 30, 2016</option>
          <option value="16">July 1, 2016 - June 30, 2017</option>
          <option value="17">July 1, 2017 - June 30, 2018</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit (12.9.2016): Still stuck on this.

I am able to grab the window handles of both the old and new windows and I am able to get the title of the new window after switching to it using driver.title. Given that I know the title of the new window once it is opened, I would think that passing that title into move_to.window(new_window_title_here) would work. However, when I call that function, Selenium throws a NoSuchWindowException. When I call switch_to.window(new_window_handle_here), my print statements confirm that I am switching to the new window, but I still cannot grab any elements. I have tried grabbing them by xpath, by name, and by CSS selector with zero luck. Could this be a bug with Selenium or the Python bindings?

Comment: Are you using `find_element_by_name` when you should be using `find_element_by_id`?

Comment: @DavidCullen There is no ID given for the element I am looking for. I prefer to use an xpath query such as "//select[@name = \"rotationsetID\"]" but I also tried using the name.

Comment: The reason I asked is that you have a query for `programID` that uses `find_element_by_id`. So I wondered if `scheduleID` was actually an `id` instead of a `name`.

Comment: @DavidCullen yeah, unfortunately I don't have an ID to work with. The element name was the only thing given, the find_element_by_id is for another element on the previous page.

Comment: Have you used the Chrome developer console to verify that you can find the element?

Comment: @DavidCullen Yes, I have located the element in the Chrome dev tools. I actually originally recorded this test script on Selenium IDE (Firefox), tweaking the selectors / Xpath queries before exporting. Everything works there, but I need the code to work with all the main browser drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `driver` instance should have a `list` named `window_handles`. You should be able to save the current and desired window handles and switch between them using `driver.switch_to_window`:

```
main_window = driver.window_handles[0]
new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
# Do something
driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

Comment: Hi David, this did not work for me. See my response to @Lucas as well as my edit.

Comment: What happens if you try `switch_to_window` instead of `switch_to.window`? Have you run this in a debugger so that you can looks at `driver.window_handles`?

Comment: `switch_to_window` is the deprecated version of `switch_to.window`

Comment: @David yes I have tried both variations switch_to_window and switch_to.window. I am running in VS Code and am able to see my window handles in the console. It looks like Selenium is grabbing the second window, but is unable to locate any of the elements contained in it.

Comment: The code in this answer is incorrect in that it assumes the common fallacy that window handles are in the order the windows or tabs were opened. The window handles in `window_handles` is explicitly unordered, per the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#get-window-handles). In the case of two window handles, if you're using `windows_handles[1]`, and that happens to return the handle associated with the most recently opened window, you're simply getting lucky, and it is not guaranteed to work every time.

Comment: @JimEvans Perhaps you could help everyone by posting a better answer.

Comment: @JimEvans, I have similar issue. What will be fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just opened a new tab after clicking a link, it **should** be the last one in the `window_handles` list so theoretically you could do:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

The better practice would be to keep track of the first window handle before opening the link and picking the one the new one that comes after opening the link.

Comment: this did not work for me. I have tried storing driver.window_handles[0] and driver.window_handles[-1] as old and new, respectively, as you suggested. If you see my edit, I also mentioned that the first line of code acting on the new window picks an item from a dropdown, which actually does work, but immediately afterward I get a NoSuchElementException on the element that I just operated on.

Comment: I'm confused, in your example you don't hit the dropdown twice, but you said it does work the first time

Comment: It sounds like you're getting to the right window. The only thing that would be happening is either you need to wait longer or your selectors are wrong. You're sure the dropdowns are in the new window and not the old? This will be hard to troubleshoot any further without seeing the page

Comment: I have added the HTML I am trying to grab. Unfortunately, after triple checking everything you just suggested, I am even more at a loss.

Comment: I must reiterate that one should not rely on window handle ordering in the `window_handles` property. See comments on other answers to this question for further details.